# Style local background image

Tags: css

How do I include a local image for the style `background-image` `URL`, that is stored outside my application?
Actually, I can only show it in Internet Explorer with this in my CSS:

```
.class {
    background-image: url(file:///C:/tempfolder/image001.bmp);
}
```

But I need it to work for any other browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, most browsers restrict mixed-domain requests like this. In this case you're connecting to a remote server while requestion local content. Even though in your case this is perfectly reasonable, this could be put to malicious use. I believe that the simple answer is: you can't do it because of security concerns.

Comment: It works in IE because IE is a terrible browser with horrible security. And the only way to "make it work" locally is if you run a web server on the local machine, and then connect to 127.0.0.1 and request an image. Even then... I think that's a gray area, some browsers consider that a different "zone" and may block it if not configured properly.

Answer (score 1):

Use relative paths, for example:

```
.class {
    background-image: url(../tempfolder/image001.bmp);
}
```

Comment: The OP seems to be asking about including images that are local to the user's machine, not relative paths.

Comment: Yes the image is stored locally on the user's machine and not in the application.