# CSS background image from network path

Tags: css, background-image

I am working on a custom solution in SharePoint.
I have a requirement to display images from a shared network path because these images are also shared with multiple MS applications i.e Dynamics AX

I am setting background image for my div as: `background-image:url(file://{server-name}/{shared-location}/filename.ext`
It works in IE. But not in Chrome! How can I make it work in other browsers as well?

*file://{server-name}/{shared-location}/filename.ext* renders the image when put to chrome url bar. But the same line dont works when set as background image for a div

I could create a virtual path for it, but I fear i might not able to do that in production. Please suggest! Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Style local background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461112/style-local-background-image)

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. Should i create some virtual directory to point to this location? Is it possible? Creating a virtual path which points to a file on a different machine? Will it work?

Comment: If the css or html file that references the image is on the same computer as the image, I believe it should work. If the file is being requested from a remote server, then I don't think it's possible due to security restrictions.

Comment: Have you tried more slashes? For me it works when writing `file://///server-name/...` and yes, that's five slashes. In IE 9, FF 21 and Chromium 28. Haven't got it working in Opera.

Comment: Doesnt work either.. I have chrome 27.0.1453.110

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
background: url("file://{server-name}/{shared-location}/filename.ext");
```

Be sure that {server-name} and {shared-location} haven't spaces and if they include slashes use forward slashes.

Comment: And if you try with 3 slashes? "file:///"

Comment: Tried that earlier doesnt work either. But if chrome renders the image when simple put to file://{server-name}/{shared-location}/filename.ext why it doesn't set it as a bg image. I fear GRC is right its because of security reasons may be? Do you think there can be another solution for it somehow!

Comment: In some projects were we had to use resources from the network, the administrator created a symbolic link to that specific folder and give access to it from the Apache server that receive the petitions. In that scenario your app and the resources are in the same machine and if the administrator allows the access to the folder from your app, then you will be able to use them in your CSS.